# How to extract emails from logs using grep

Tags: grep

I have more than hundred log files and in each file I have between 0 and 20 lines in following format:

> [2016-06-08 18:12:32] production.INFO: Successfully done something. Email: foo@bar.com []
>   {"user":"anonymous","url":"/something","ip":"77.46.189.212","http_method":"POST","server":"www.mysite.com","referrer":"www.mysite.com/something","unique_id":"V1hD7lJ10JkAAAQ7MgsAAAAa"}

How I  can with grep extract all emails from those file but taking just those lines where in front of the email appears `Successfully done something. Email:`?

In other words email from the next line should be ignored:

> [2016-06-08 17:13:29] production.INFO: User another@email.com logged
>   out ... []
>   {"user":"another@email.com","url":"/admin/logout","ip":"109.92.131.202","http_method":"GET","server":"mysite.com","referrer":"www.mysite.com/admin/foo","unique_id":"V1g2GVJ10JkAAAqy42gAAABH"}

From given example I would like to extract `foo@bar.com` and to ignore `another@email.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to both check if the "Successfully done something." line occurs and also it contains an email:

```
awk '/Successfully done something. Email:/ && \  # match line
     match($0, /Email: ([^ ]*) /, matches) {     # match up to space
         print matches[1]                        # print captured group
     }' file
```

With your given data:

```
$ awk '/Successfully done something. Email:/ && match($0, /Email: ([^ ]*) /, matches) {print matches[1]}' file
foo@bar.com
```

Comment: Should I replace `file` with real file name?
Can I somehow run ti to apply for all files?

I have tried to execute `awk '/Successfully done something. Email:/ && match($0, /Email: ([^ ]*) /, matches) {print matches[1]}'  myfile1.log`

  but following error is reported: `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,`

Comment: @gandra404 you can replace `file` with some globbing like `/var/log/http/*log` to match as many files as you want. However, from the error you get it looks like you are running a different awk than I do (`awk --version` tells you). Mine is GNU awk, probably yours does not allow the 3rd parameter of [`match()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), that is a pity :/

Comment: your comment helped me a lot. First I have tried on vbox ubuntu. After your comments I have copied files on another ubuntu on digitaloceanand now works!!!! Thanks. Now accepting your answer.

Comment: @gandra404 great! GNU awk is cool, so it is always worth looking for a server having it :)

Answer (score 0):

If your version of grep supports perl regexes, then you could try something like that

```
grep -r 'Successfully done something. Email:' /path/to/logs/ | grep -oP '\S+@\S+'
```

You might want to replace the regex in the second `grep` with a better one.

You can also do in with a single `grep`:

```
grep -roP 'Successfully done something. Email: \K\S+@\S+' /path/to/logs/'
```

Comment: I have positioned inside folder with log files  and  tried `grep 'Successfully done something. Email:' . | grep -P '\S+@\S+'`. Here is the output: `grep: .: Is a directory`

Comment: Then either replace `.` by a `*`, or add the `-r` parameter (i.e. `grep -r ...`).

Comment: Now without errors but this prints all matching lines instead only emails.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I forgot the `-o` parameter in the second `grep`. I updated the answer.